# iOS:How to set the color of the text view's modal mail compose controller's navigation bar?

Tags: email, hyperlink, textview, navigationbar, appearance

When the user long presses email link in `UITextView`, and selects new message option, system presents mail compose controller. I would like to change its navigation bar color (or appearance).

Any easy way to do it?

Comment: I think there is no way to do that, at least from your app, as mail composing view is part of Mail app.

Comment: I could do this with [UINavigationBar appearance], but I can't find the delegate or notification to know when this controller is being presented, or dismissed

Answer (score 0):

Using RGB:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[[mailer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```